# Can one construct any n-gon if angle trisection is also allowed?

Tags: galois-theory, geometric-construction

Suppose one is asked to construct a regular $n$-gon, but with one extra operation allowed in addition to the standard compass-and-straightedge ones: trisecting any angle.

- Are all $n$-gons constructible now?
- If not, which ones aren't?

What other operations do we need to add to our "toolbox" to make it possible to construct $n$-gons for all $n$? Of course, I suppose allowing $n$-section of angles for all integers $n$ would make it easy, but can it be done with less?

Comment: According to [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendecagon), the 11-gon is not constructible from straightedge, compass, and trisections.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PierpontPrime.html

Comment: It suffices to allow $n$-sections for all prime $n$, but maybe that's obvious. More interesting is that I think if one prime is omitted then it's not enough (but I haven't thought this through carefully).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: you're right - it follows from the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions and from considering degrees of number fields.

Comment: So one must allow p-section of angles for all prime p to make all n-gons constructible? I'd appreciate someone turning this into an answer. :)

Comment: To construct a 31-gon, you would need to perform an angle quintisection in addition to a trisection, as $31-1=2*3*5$. To construct a regular 44100000001-gon, you need to perform eight angle quintisections and two septisections in addition to two angle trisections. To divide an angle into 5, 7, 11, *et cetera* parts, you can use an Archimedean spiral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do if you have an angle trisector:

1. Construct a regular $n$-gon when n has no prime factors greater than 3.
2. Construct a regular $n+1$-gon for any of the above values of $n$ if $n+1$ is prime.  Such primes are called Pierpont primes.
3. Construct a regular $m$-gon when $m$ is a product of distinct Pierpont primes, a power of 2 and a power of 3.  The powers of 2 and 3 could be $a^0 = 1$.

For example $13 =12+1$ is a Pierpont prime, so that's good, but $11$ does not fit any of the possibilities given above.  (The regular $11$-gon can be constructed with the more powerful tool of neusis; currently this is the only known prime covered by neusis but not by Eucliean tools plus angle trisector alone.)